# RuntimeError: You need to use the eventlet server

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

I'm setting up my Flask application like the following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO()
socketio.init_app(app)

# All the code ...
```

When running uWSGI, I pass these parameters:

```
uwsgi --socket app.sock --http-websockets --master --wsgi-file app.py --callable app
```

But doing this, I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: You need to use the eventlet server. See the Deployment section of the documentation for more information.

I suspect that the `app`returned by my code does not wrap the SocketIO system, so when using uwsgi, it fails using eventlet.

What should I serve to uwsgi to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

uWSGI works in combination with gevent, not with eventlet. It appears you have eventlet installed in your virtualenv, and this is confusing things. Uninstall eventlet, install gevent (if you haven't yet) and then I think you'll get a better result.

Comment: I had, indeed. But then I removed it and the error was still present. I also forced using async_mode on Flask-SocketIO, with no luck :/

Comment: Please update your question with the output that you get now. I assume the eventlet error message went away?

Comment: I actually ran into the same error, it appeared that even if I specify gevent as gunicorn's worker class,  it's still running with eventlet with the `Server initialized for eventlet.` logging message. After I uninstalled eventlet, the problem went away and it's running with gevent as expected.

Comment: Right. I explicitly indicated that you have to uninstall eventlet. If you intend to keep it installed, then you have to force gevent by passing `async_mode='gevent_uwsgi'`.