# What does "RuntimeError: You need to use the eventlet server" mean? Why do my sockets still work?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-socketio

I am building a flask application and am attempting to use flask-socketio.

It seems like everything is working; I can successfully trigger a socket method from a client but I am periodically receiving this Runtime Error.

I have been having some issues with getting sockets working with to my file structure, so maybe this is the cause. I currently have the following:

/project/run.py

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

/project/app/**init**.py

```
socketio = SocketIO()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
   
    # init socket
    socketio.init_app(app)
    

    from .routes import main, auth    # import after app declaration to avoid circular
    
    # Register the main blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    app.register_blueprint(auth)

    return app
```

then I just do `from app import socketio` and that seems to work? I am not entirely sure this is the correct way to do this.

I have tried playing around with the file structure, but looking online, it seems like it is an issue with how I run the server? [RuntimeError: You need to use the eventlet server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62309511/runtimeerror-you-need-to-use-the-eventlet-server) did not make much sense to me.

Ideally I would like to continue running the server how it is, and I am not really sure why I would need a different way to run the server as I have used sockets in flask on the normal localhost flask server before.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `app.run()` to run your server. This is how you run Flask servers. Flask-SocketIO apps run with a different statement:

```
socketio.run(app)
```

The error is telling you that you have eventlet installed and Flask-SocketIO wants to use it, but you started a server that is not eventlet. Starting the app with the above statement will run the eventlet server.

The fact that your sockets work is not really accurate observation. The sockets are working in polling mode, but they cannot upgrade to WebSocket due to this server mismatch.